# Trouble with JSON decoding ... JSONException : end of input at character 0

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm using HTTP encryption. if the encryption is false, webservice send a simple JSON with the value false and if the encryption is right, I send JSON array with datas.

test() is the method that "try" the api with a set of login:password.

I have trouble using the JSON that I receive (JSONException : End of input at character 0 )

Here's the entiere code (I don't think that this whole code will serve but...) and just after the code that make a JSON Exception :

```
private void test(String l, String p) {
        Log.v("MWW", "test de DialogBoxAuth");

        TextView erreur = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.erreurtext);
        String url = Main.app_preferences.getString("domain", "domain")+"api.php/1.0/authenticate";
        WebService webService = new WebService(url);
        Log.v("MWW", ".:" + url);

        // creation d'un MAP
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // Réponse JSON via le webservice avec les parametres

        response = webService.webGet("", params, l, p);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        Log.v("MWW", "entity = " + response.getEntity().toString());

        if (entity != null) {
            try {
                ret = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                Log.v("MWW", "ret = " + ret.toString());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Groshie:", e.getMessage());
            }

            try {
                Log.v("MWW", "01");
                JSONArray childs = new JSONArray(ret);
                Log.v("MWW", "02");

                // affiche le JSON
                Log.v("MWW", "-->" + childs.toString());

                Log.v("MWW", "03");
                for (int j = 0; j < childs.length(); j++) {

                    JSONObject childNodeJSON = childs.getJSONObject(j);
                    // On récupère les données une par une et on les set dans la classe adéquate
                    String ok = "ok";
                    if (childNodeJSON.getString("status").equals(ok)) {
                        MajLoginPassword(l, p);
                        dismiss();
                        break;
                    } else {
                        erreur.setText("Login ou password incorrect");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            erreur.setText("Vérifiez votre connexion à internet");
        }
    }
```

The code that provide the Exception :

```
if (entity != null) {
            try {
                ret = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                Log.v("MWW", "ret = " + ret.toString());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Groshie:", e.getMessage());
            }

            try {
                Log.v("MWW", "01");
                JSONArray childs = new JSONArray(ret);
                Log.v("MWW", "02");
```

I can see the Logcat "01" but not the "02", so "org.Json.JSONException : End of input at character 0" the error is coming from this line :

```
JSONArray childs = new JSONArray(ret);
```

Where and Why this Exception is leaved?

I can fix this problem alone... I dont understand it ! 
MANY thanks to read my problem, Clem'

Ok, many thanks ! After reading your comments, I've updated the code :

```
try {
                Log.v("MMW", "01 : ret = " + ret.toString());

                //JSONArray childs = new JSONArray(ret);
                JSONObject childs = new JSONObject(ret);

                Log.v("MMW", "02");

                // affiche le JSON
                Log.v("MMW", "-->" + childs.toString());

                Log.v("MMW", "03");
                for (int j = 0; j < childs.length(); j++) {


                    //JSONObject childNodeJSON = childs.getJSONObject(j);
                    JSONObject childNodeJSON = childs;

                    // On récupère les données une par une et on les set dans la classe adéquate
                    String ok = "ok";
                    if (childNodeJSON.getString("status").equals(ok)) {
                        MajLoginPassword(l, p);
                        dismiss();
                        break;
                    } else {
                        erreur.setText("Login ou password incorrect");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            erreur.setText("Vérifiez votre connexion à internet");
        }
```

But there is a new exception:

```
JSONException : end of input at character 0 of ...
```

And the logcat says

```
ret = 
01 : ret =
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing

```
JSONArray childs = new JSONArray(ret);
```

to

```
JSONObject childs = new JSONObject(ret);
```

I had similar issues when trying to use a JSONArray initially. Since all JSON classes derive from JSONObject, this should work.

Comment: thanks :D but there is an exception. The "ret" show nothing, it would say that there is no JSON received ? Thanks

Comment: It looks like you have determined that ret is null or empty from you edited question. Now you should figure out why your webservice call is returning nothing. Have you looked at the webservice object? Is it returning 404 or something else? Also, have you made sure you are requesting internet permissions in your manifest?

Comment: Yes, the internet connexion is running and return nothing apparently... SO I will alter webservice... THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Make sure 'ret' is valid Json by logging and use

```
JSONObject childs = new JSONObject(ret);
```

instead of JSonArray.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my initial post, I've again a problem ... (ret is empty?) THX

Comment: Make sure there is valid Json string in ret, that will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that `"ret"` is not a String which represents a valid JSONArray. Print that value and make sure that it is a valid JSON String for building an array.

Answer (score 0):

I received nothign from the webserver, that's it!
I'm coding to show an information instread of this fatal crash ;-)